# How do you find the projector appearing in $\kappa$-symmetry for Green-Schwarz formulation of superstring?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, string-theory, dirac-matrices

I am trying to study the Green-Schwarz formulation of the superstring and I am following the string theory book by Becker, Becker, Schwarz. In there, they consider the action
$$
S = S_1 + S_2 = -\frac{1}{\pi} \int \mathrm{d}^2\sigma \sqrt{-G} + \frac{1}{\pi} \int\,\,(\bar{\Theta}^1\Gamma_\mu\mathrm{d}\Theta^1-\bar{\Theta}^2\Gamma_\mu\mathrm{d}\Theta^2)\mathrm{d}X^\mu - \bar{\Theta}^1\Gamma_\mu\mathrm{d}\Theta^1\bar{\Theta}^2\Gamma^\mu\mathrm{d}\Theta^2~,
$$
where $\Theta^A, A=1,2$ are Majorana-Weyl spinors in 10d and $G$ is the determinant of the pullback metric:
$$
G = \mathrm{det} G_{\alpha\beta}~,~~~ G_{\alpha\beta} = \Pi_\alpha\cdot\Pi_\beta~,~~~\Pi^\mu_\alpha = \partial_\alpha X^\mu - \bar{\Theta}^A \Gamma^\mu \partial_\alpha \Theta^A~.
$$

They then consider the local fermionic transformations
$$
\delta X^\mu = \bar{\Theta}^A \Gamma^\mu \delta\Theta^A~.
$$
Using this they calculate
$$
\delta S_1 = \frac{2}{\pi} \int \mathrm{d}^2\sigma \sqrt{-G} G^{\alpha\beta} \Pi^\mu_{\alpha} \delta\bar{\Theta}^A \Gamma_\mu \partial_\beta \Theta^A~,
$$
and
$$
\delta S_2 = \frac{2}{\pi} \int \mathrm{d}^2\sigma \varepsilon^{\alpha\beta} (\delta \bar{\Theta}^1 \Gamma_\mu \partial_\alpha \Theta^1 -\delta \bar{\Theta}^2 \Gamma_\mu \partial_\alpha\Theta^2)\Pi^\mu_\beta~.
$$
Both of these I can follow and get the same result. However, they then claim that in equation (5.51) on page 158 that this combines to give
$$
\delta S = \frac{4}{\pi}\int\mathrm{d}^2\sigma\varepsilon^{\alpha\beta}(\delta\bar{\Theta}^1 P_+ \Gamma_\mu \partial_\alpha \Theta^1 - \delta\bar{\Theta}^2P_- \Gamma_\mu \partial_\alpha \Theta^2) \Pi^\mu_\beta~,
$$
where $P_\pm$ are projectors that are introduced and given by
$$
P_\pm = \frac12 (1 \pm \gamma)~,~~~\gamma = - \frac{\varepsilon^{\alpha\beta} \Pi_\alpha^\mu \Pi_\beta^\nu \Gamma_{\mu\nu}}{2 \sqrt{-G}}~.
$$

I can see that the identity part of $P_\pm$ in $\delta S$ corresponds directly to the variation $\delta S_2$ and thus the $\gamma$-part must correspond to $\delta S_1$. However, I am unable to see how? Expanding the $A$-index contraction gets you close but I am confused as to how to transform this expression to something resembling $\gamma$. How does the $\sqrt{-G}$ go from the numerator to denominator? Does anyone know how this works/can give me some pointers?